# React don't want to render Maps component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Trying to learn React and integrate Google Maps API for JS. In `App.jsx` I have Routing:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} layout={LandingLayout} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

In `LandingLayout` I have sidebar implementation from `Semantic UI` because I want to show sidebar everywhere, so it is my layout. In component `LandingPage` I have these lines of code:

`return <MapContainer />;`

And in `MapContainer` I have copy-pasted code from Google Maps React documentation: [DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#sample-usage-with-lazy-loading-google-api)

Sidebar is loaded and everything is OK, but Google maps don't want to render and I don't have any idea why..

Comment: Have you styled the map component so that it has dimensions ?

Comment: I have used the same npm package and you have to add height and width to your map. So within render you need to add something like this 
const style = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100vh',
      position: 'relative'
    }
and then:
<div style={style}> to your root div.

Comment: I have added it into MapContainer `<Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'left' }}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: 40.854885,
          lng: -88.081807,
        }}
      >`

Answer (score 1):

With-out seeing your code I think it's probably just the size of the `MapContainer` is not defined as others mentioned in the comments. If it's another problem please show more code.

I would add a wrapper div around the `MapContainer` component with `width: 100%; height:100%;` style. In the demo I've also added a style to `html,body` to make it full page size (see `styles.css`).

It should work like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq28wp08ry). (Map not loading in the Sandbox because the API key is not correct.)